# Simple variable incremenration excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I can't work out why a simple vba code won't increment a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub regression_coeff()

Dim x1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, i As Integer
Dim inc As Integer

inc = 1
x1 = 1
x2 = 1

   For i = 0 To 10



   x2 = x2 + 1

   Next i

   End

'x1 = x1 / x
'x2 = x2 / x



Cells(1, 3).Value = x1
'Cells(1, 4).Value = x2



End Sub
```

I thought it might be due to the variable definition but it didn't help 
Cheers

D

Comment: I am not sure what that `End` statement does, but I think I'd remove it.

Comment: `x2` is what is being incremented, but `x1` shouldn't change.

Comment: `End` does exactly that - it stops your code at that statement.  Remove it.

Comment: I'm new to vba - just playing around. I'm used to ending for loops in other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub regression_coeff()

Dim x1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, i As Integer
Dim inc As Integer

inc = 1
x1 = 1
x2 = 1

   For i = 0 To 10

   x2 = x2 + 1

   Next i

'x1 = x1 / x
'x2 = x2 / x

Cells(1, 3).Value = x1
Cells(1, 4).Value = x2

End Sub
```

It works by me like this. The problem with your code was the `End`, which stops it. Here is a bit more about [END](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wt87xba.aspx).